# Several types with OR with one generic position method

Tags: scala, generics, refactoring

I have two types of data: String and extend from SpecificRecordBase and the several methods  with the same business logic to process this data, except using java methods from another library which I cant change.

```
  def createResultStreamSpecificRecordBase[T <: SpecificRecordBase](topic: String, source: DataStream[KafkaSourceType])(
      implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): DataStream[T] = {
      // contain calling java method with T <: SpecificRecordBase
      serialize(source, topic)  
      // the same logic
  }

  def createResultStreamString(topic: String, source: DataStream[KafkaSourceType]): DataStream[String] = {
      // dont contain calling java method with T <: SpecificRecordBase
      // the same logic
  }

  def processSpecificRecordBase[T <: SpecificRecordBase](...)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): Unit = {
      val stream = createStreamSpecificRecordBase(topic, source)
      // the other the same process actions
  }

  def processString(...): Unit = {
      val stream = createResultStreamString(topic, source)
      // the other the same process actions
  }
```

I want to remove the duplicated code in process methods and write single. Could you write please how to do it? Is it possible to use something like OR in generic types?

```
  def process[T <: SpecificRecordBase ?OR? String](...)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): Unit = {
      val stream = createStream(topic, source)

      this match {
          case SpecificRecordBaseRunner() => createStreamSpecificRecordBase(topic, source)
          case StringRunner()             => createStreamString(topic, source)
      }
      // the other process actions
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately right now there is no `OR` type operator as you described. The good news that, `Union Types` feature is a part of upcoming Dotty:
https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/union-types.html

Right now such problems solved usually with next approaches:

***Sum types***

You can declare `sealed trait` which will box all possible instances.
Please, see next code example for more details:

```
// This is your base of sum type
sealed trait TopicResult

//Declared instances which you need to handle
case class RecordResult[T <: SpecificRecordBase](tag: ClassTag[T]) extends TopicResult
case object StringResult extends TopicResult

//Helper methods goes here for convenience 
object TopicResult {
    def record[T <: SpecificRecordBase](implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): TopicResult = RecordResult(tag)
    def string: TopicResult = StringResult
  }

def process(result: TopicResult /*other arguments*/): Unit = {
  // This pattern matching should be safe, because you know all instances in advance.
  result match {
    case RecordResult(tag) => createStreamSpecificRecordBase(topic, source)
    case StringResult => createStreamString(topic, source)
  }
  /// other operations
}
```

***Ad-hoc polymorphous***

Also known as `Type Class` pattern. You can extract behavior based on it's type. This is quite popular approach, you may see in libraries like `cats`, `circe` etc.
Please, see code example below for more details:

```
// Type dependent logic interface
trait CreateTopic[T] {
 def createTopic(topic: String, source: String): String // put desired result type here
}

object CreateTopic {
  implicit def recordCreateTopic[T <: SpecificRecordBase](implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): CreateTopic[T] = {
    (topic: String, source: String) => ??? // create topic for record base
  }

  implicit val stringCreateTopic: CreateTopic[String] = {
    (topic: String, source: String) => ??? // create topic for record base
  }
}

import CreateTopic._
// implementation will be substituted by compiler based on it's type, from implicit context 
def process[T](/*other arguments*/)(implicit create: CreateTopic[T]): Unit = {
  create.createTopic(topic, source)
  /// other operations
}
```

Excuse me, I'm not an Kafka expert, so please correct me if you will find some parts, which does not make sens from Kafka point of view.

Hope this helps!